# Borel Measures: Lusin

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

*I'm trying to self-learn.*

Given the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Consider a Borel measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}:\quad\mu\geq0$$

Regard a measurable:
$$f\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}):\quad \mu\{f\neq0\}<\infty$$

Then one finds:
$$g\in\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{C}):\quad\mu\{f\neq g\}<\varepsilon$$

Together with:
$$\|g\|_\infty\leq\|f\|_\infty$$
How can I prove this?

Comment: What is $L^2$ of a complex measure?

Comment: $L^2(\mu)=L^2(|\mu|)$.

Comment: With respect to its total measure $|\mu|$.

Comment: @Freeze_S As I pointed out in my very first comment here on MSE: It really seems to me you might benefit from a book on measure theory. Follland _Real Analysis_ is excellent. Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_ is excellent A certain number of your questions are very standard results. Like this one; it's true for (regular) Borel measures on any compact Hausdorff space. Just a thought...

Comment: In that case, recall any $\chi_E$ is the $|\mu|$-a.e.limit of a sequence $f_n\in C(\Omega)$ with $|f_n|\le 1$ for all $n.$

Comment: @zhw: How can convergence depend on the measure?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Found it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Freeze_S No charge. It's not true that there exist continuous $f_n$ that tend to $\chi_E$ at _every_ point. The most you can say is almost everywhere. The meaning of "almost everywhere" depends on the measure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is Community Wiki!*

**Construction**

Denote compact sets:
$$\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{C}):=\{K\subseteq\mathbb{C}:K\text{ compact}\}$$

Suppose it is positive:
$$f\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}):\quad f\geq0$$

And it is bounded:
$$\Delta_n:=2^{-n}\|f\|_\infty<\infty$$

Also compact support:
$$K:=\overline{\{f\neq0\}}\in\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{C})$$

By local compactness:
$$K\subseteq U\subseteq\overline{U}\in\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{C})$$

Construct functions:
$$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}k\Delta_n1_{\{k\Delta_n\leq f<(k+1)\Delta_n\}}$$

Regard the differences:
$$\Delta s_n:=s_n-s_{n-1}=\Delta_n1_{A_n}$$

By finite measure:
$$K_n\subseteq A_n\subseteq U_n\subseteq U$$

That has measure:
$$\mu(\Delta A_n):=\mu(U_n\setminus K_n)\leq2^{-n}\varepsilon$$

So one obtains:
$$\mu(\Delta A):=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\Delta A_n\right)\leq\varepsilon$$

By Urysohn's lemma:
$$h_n\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{C}):\quad1_{K_n}\leq h_n\leq1_{U_n}$$

By uniform convergence:
$$g:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta_nh_n\in\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{C})$$

Then one derives:
$$x\notin\Delta A:\quad g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta_n h_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta s_n(x)=f(x)$$

Concluding the construction.

**Extension**

For noncompact support:
$$K\in\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{C}):\quad\mu(A\setminus K)<\varepsilon$$

For complex functions:
$$f=\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha f_\alpha:\quad f_\alpha\geq0$$

For unbounded functions:
$$f:=1_{\{|f|\leq N_\varepsilon\}}f:\quad\mu\{|f|>N_\varepsilon\}<\varepsilon$$

For the boundedness:
$$g':=\varphi\circ g:\quad\varphi(z):=z1_{\{|z|>\|f\|_\infty\}}+\|f\|_\infty\frac{z}{|z|}1_{\{|z|>\|f\|_\infty\}}$$

Concluding extension.